# Sending emails without using mail server from customer premises

Tags: node.js, sockets, email

I have software running in customer servers on premises and  there are multiple software and I want  on failure of any software it should send emails to me 
 It can be a pain enabling & configuring to work with the customers mail servers.
 I thought to write simple socket program in NodeJS to read the error log file and push those messages to my server that should handle the sending email
or may be web service to call for sending email.
If any has used things like this please tell me or Is there any easy solution exist somewhere?

**Updating my question**

As per comments I tried to implement same solution here is my main nodejs server file and where exactly I am facing problem now in Socket event emit. I want to emit socket event whenever log.xml file get changes, This run only one time.

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
parser = new require('xml2json'),
fs = require('fs');

app.listen(8030);

console.log('server listening on localhost:8030');

// creating a new websocket to keep the content updated without REST call
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(__dirname);
    // reading the log file
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/var/home/apache/log.xml', function (err, data) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        // parsing the new xml data and converting them into json file
        var json = parser.toJson(data);
        // send the new data to the client
        socket.emit('error', json);
    });

});

/* Email send services This code to in my client server outside of main socket server cloud This part is working fine I tested it in my different server

var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8030');
socket.on('error', function (data) {
// convert the json string into a valid javascript object
var _data = JSON.parse(data);
mySendMailTest(_data);

    */
```

Please apologies me as I am new to stackoverflow community.

Comment: Please tell us what exact problem you are facing in your code and if you just want to read log files you use node fs module to read and parse log file and you can push msg to socket

Comment: It is very simple thing to do as I think but your question is misguiding please update it  if you really need an answer

Comment: @Shad  Please don't down vote my question, I am new to stackoverflow , As I posted my question there were suddenly downvote without any comments. but any way you added comments that is helpful I have updated the question with one another problem in same solution.

Comment: There is reason to downvote questions coz stackoverflow search index will not pick on first priority the  downvoted questions when someone search questions just to help other users. as I think I don't downvote without comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no problem in your socket code you need to use fs.watchFile before reading file. this is watch function similar to Angular Watch , it will detect any change happen to your file and run another function in callback to emit the socket

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener

```
 // creating a new websocket to keep the content updated without REST call
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log(__dirname);
         // reading the log file
         // watching the file
          fs.watchFile(__dirname + '/var/home/apache/log.xml', function(curr, prev) {
         // on file change just read it 

        fs.readFile(__dirname + '/var/home/apache/log.xml', function (err, data)    {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            // parsing the new xml data and converting them into json file
            var json = parser.toJson(data);
            // send the new data to the client
            socket.emit('error', json);
        });
       });
    });
```